# Help with Thévenin model

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I've been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong when trying to obtain the Thévenin model for this DC circuit assuming the load to be C2.

[image]

The equivalent model I get is the following:

[image]

And then I just add the load C2, like so:

[image]

However, when I simulate the circuits (original and Thévenin) and measure the output at C2, I get different charging times, and if, for example, I give R2 a larger value than R1 the charging time difference is even worse. If I do it the other way around (R1 greater than R2), the charging times between the original circuit and the equivalent are similar, but not the same, so I am definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: @All - The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments have been moved to chat & should be continued there (see the link in the next comment below). -- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!* When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, please answer it as usual. Any updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit] to the question, not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: *Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143073/discussion-on-question-by-lm555cn-help-with-thevenin-model); please do not continue the discussion here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thevenin's original theorem was based on a complicated network of resistors and a dc voltage source.

It has been applied to ac impedance although at a single frequency. In this case the impedance is expressed as $$Z_{Th}=R_{Th}+jX_{Th}.$$ While Thevenin replaced the complicated network with a single resistor, the ac approach required two components, a resistor and either a capacitor or inductor.

For the circuit in the OP, a step input requires analysis at many frequencies. So only a **Thevenin-like** approach can be used. Here is the reason:

Looking at the impedance presented to \$C_2\$, it can be seen that the impedance is resistive at dc and at very high frequencies and capacitive other wise. While this can be represented as an impedance with a real part and an imaginary part it is found that the real part is not constant but is frequency dependant as shown later. So a more complicated collection of passive components are required to perfom a Thevenin-like reduction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fif2vF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With \$C_2\$ removed there is no current through \$R_2\$. So by the Voltage divider rule, $$V_{Th}=V_{ab}=V_{cb}=\frac{1}{R_{1}C_{1}s+1}V_{G}$$

The Norton current, \$I_{N}\$, can be found by shorting node a to nobe b then finding the current through the short.$$I_{N}=\frac{1}{R_{1}+R_{2}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_{1}R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}C_{1}s}V_{G}$$

Next, \$Z_{Th}\$ can be found as:$$Z_{Th}=\frac{V_{Th}}{I_{N}}=\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)\frac{\frac{R_{1}R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}C_{1}s+1}{R_{1}C_{1}s+1}=R_{12}\frac{\tau_{2}s+1}{\tau_{1}s+1}$$
where: \$\tau_{1}=R_1C_1, \tau_{2}=\frac{R_{1}R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}C_{1}\$.

Forming into the standard form and setting \$s=j\omega\$:$$Z_{Th}(\omega)=R_{Th}(\omega)+jX_{Th}(\omega)=\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)\frac{\tau_{1}\tau_{2}\omega^{2}+1}{\left(\tau_{1}\omega\right)^{2}+1}-j\left(R_{1}+R_{2}\right)\frac{\left(\tau_{1}-\tau_{2}\right)\omega}{\left(\tau_{1}\omega\right)^{2}+1}$$

The 12V-step input voltage is represented in the Laplace domain as $$V_G(s)=\frac{12}{s}.$$ So$$V_{Th}=\frac{12}{s(R_{1}C_{1}s+1)}.$$

In time domain:$$v_{Th}(t)=12\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau_1}}\right)$$
Clearly there is no configuration of two passive elements that can provide this impedance. But it can be done with three. Since this result is derived from three elements, they can be reused as shown in LTspice simulation below. It s clear that the VO from the original circuit, matches exactly with the result from the Thevenin-like equivalent circuit.

Whether this can be called a Thevenin equivilant circuit or not I cannot say. It was certainly performed in a Thevenin spirit. (Cheers)

[image]

Comment: @RusselH - Answer accepted, thank you very much for your detailed explanation, and to all who answered as well.  Apparently with such a circuit in DC, it can't be as easy to obtain directly a single Vth and Rth, according to the Thévenin's theorem, therefore recurring to how RussellH solved it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

May as well answer this one now. It may have future value for those interested in solving differential equations.

This process may discourage those less interested in seeing unique shapes and topologies or about getting into the mathematical weeds. The fact is, though, that the 2-stage RC filter is actually the first level at which the curve shapes and differential equations are no longer trivial and begin to get more interesting.

Let's draw out the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpuLav.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm assuming that the capacitors are initially discharged and that the switch will be active (connecting \$V\$ to the rest of the circuit) at \$t=0\$. The problem is to solve the differential equations here for both \$V_1\$ and for \$V_2\$.

I'll use KCL to start:

$$\begin{align*}
V_1:&&\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_1}{R_2}+C_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_1 &= \frac{V}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_2}
\\\\
&&\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_1+\frac1{C_1}\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\right)V_1 &= \frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}V+\frac{1}{R_2\,C_1}V_2
\\\\
&&\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{C_1}\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\right)\right]V_1 &= \frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}V+\frac{1}{R_2\,C_1}V_2
\\\\
V_2:&&\frac{V_2}{R_2}+C_2\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_2&=\frac{V_1}{R_2}
\\\\
&&\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_2+\frac{1}{R_2\,C_2}V_2&=\frac{1}{R_2\,C_2}V_1
\\\\
&&\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{R_2\,C_2}\right]V_2&=\frac{1}{R_2\,C_2}V_1
\end{align*}$$

There are three obvious time constants above. I'll write these at the top and then re-write the above to use them:

$$\begin{align*}
&&\tau_{_1} &= R_1\,C_1\\&&\tau_{_2} &= R_2\,C_2\\&&\tau_{_3} &= R_2\,C_1
\\\\
V_1:&&\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\left(\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}\right)\right]V_1 &= \frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}V+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}V_2
\\\\
V_2:&&\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}\right]V_2&=\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}V_1
\end{align*}$$

Substituting the \$V_2\$ equation into the \$V_1\$ equation, find:

$$\begin{align*}\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\left(\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}\right)\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}\right]V_2 &= \frac{1}{\tau_{_1}\,\tau_{_2}}V+\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}\,\tau_{_3}}V_2
\\\\
\left\{\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\left(\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}\right)\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}\right]-\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}\,\tau_{_3}}\right\}V_2 &= \frac{1}{\tau_{_1}
\,\tau_{_2}}V
\\\\
\left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+\left(\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}\right)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}\,\tau_{_2}}\right]V_2 &= \frac{1}{\tau_{_1}
\,\tau_{_2}}V
\end{align*}$$

The right side is a constant. So differentiating both sides once more causes the right side to become zero. This makes the resulting \$V_2\$ equation homogeneous:

$$\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+\left(\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}\right)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}\,\tau_{_2}}\right]V_2 &= \left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right]\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}
\,\tau_{_2}}V
\\\\
\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+\left(\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}\right)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}\,\tau_{_2}}\right]V_2 &= 0
\end{align*}$$

Look back at the equation for \$V_1\$. The operator(s) needed to make the right side zero may seem tricky, for a second, but the above tells us exactly what's needed to cause the function \$V_2\$ to go to zero. Just apply the operators already just determined above for \$V_2\$ to both sides of the equation for \$V_1\$. That pair of operators will certainly kill the right side, forcing it to zero, and thereby creating the following homogeneous equation for \$V_1\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\left(\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}\right)\right]V_1 &= \frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}V+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}V_2
\\\\
\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+\left(\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}\right)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}\,\tau_{_2}}\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\left(\frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}}\right)\right]V_1 &= 0
\end{align*}$$

That's it. Both equations can now be readily solved, independently. Before I start, I'm introducing some simplifying new constants to reduce scribbling:

$$\begin{align*}
&&a = \frac{1}{\tau_{_1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{_3}},\quad b = \frac{1}{\tau_{_1}\,\tau_{_2}},\quad c&=\frac{1}{\tau_{_2}}
\\\\
V_1:&&\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+a\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+b\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+a-c\right]V_1 &= 0
\\\\
V_2:&&\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+a\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+b\right]V_2 &= 0
\end{align*}$$

The \$\left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}+a\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+b\right]\$ form should be put into the standard form: \$\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right)^2+\beta^2\right]\$. (Easier to then scribble out a solution.) So some more constants and a re-write:

$$\begin{align*}
&&\alpha=-\frac12 a,\quad \beta=\frac12\sqrt{4b-a^2},\quad r=c-a
\\\\
V_1:&&\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-0\right]\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right)^2+\beta^2\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-r\right]V_1 &= 0
\\\\
V_2:&&\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-0\right]\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right)^2+\beta^2\right]V_2 &= 0
\end{align*}$$

Now, scribble out solutions:

$$\begin{align*}
V_1&=A_1+\exp\left(\alpha\,t\right)\left[A_3\cos\left(\beta\,t\right)+A_4\sin\left(\beta\,t\right)\right]+A_2\exp\left(r\,t\right)
\\\\
V_2&=A_5+\exp\left(\alpha\,t\right)\left[A_6\cos\left(\beta\,t\right)+A_7\sin\left(\beta\,t\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

Just seven constants to work out. This should be easy!

Oh, wait! There's another issue. Note the sine and cosine? I don't expect that in a simple RC circuit. No damped sinusoidal stuff. If and only if \$\beta\$ is imaginary can the resulting equations be:

$$\begin{align*}
V_1&=A_1+\exp\left(\alpha\,t\right)\left[A_3\cosh\left(\frac{\beta}{i}\,t\right)+A_4\sinh\left(\frac{\beta}{i}\,t\right)\right]+A_2\exp\left(r\,t\right)
\\\\
V_2&=A_5+\exp\left(\alpha\,t\right)\left[A_6\cosh\left(\frac{\beta}{i}\,t\right)+A_7\sinh\left(\frac{\beta}{i}\,t\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

That looks more sensible. But is it? \$\beta\$ is imaginary if \$4b-a^2\lt 0\$. I'll leave it as an exercise. (But it is true and if pursued the answer will turn on the minimum value for \$y\$ when \$y=x+\frac1{x}+C\$.)

Regarding the constants, I'll move along a little faster. Assuming discharged capacitors at \$t=0\$, then the general solution for \$V_1\$ provides \$A_1+A_2+A_3=0\$ and the general solution for \$V_2\$ provides \$A_5+A_6=0\$. Placing the general solution for \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ back into the KCL equations (at \$t=0\$), and performing the derivatives as appropriate, then provides \$A_2\, r+A_3\,\alpha=\frac1{\tau_{_1}}V\$ from the first KCL equation and \$A_6\,\alpha+A_7\,\beta=0\$ from the second KCL equation.

\$A_4\$ is a little bit of a pain. But noting that \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_1\$ at \$t=0\$ is the current through \$R_1\$ divided by \$C_1\$, so \$A_2\,r+A_3\,\alpha+A_4\,\beta=\frac{V}{\tau_{_1}}\$ and from that it's possible to then realize \$A_4=0\$.

Looking at \$t\to \infty\$, find \$A_1=V\$, \$A_2=V\frac{1+\alpha\,\tau_{_1}}{\tau_{_1}\left(r-\alpha\right)}\$, \$A_3=-V\frac{1+r\,\tau_{_1}}{\tau_{_1}\left(r-\alpha\right)}\$, \$A_5=V\$, \$A_6=-V\$, and \$A_7=V\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\$.

That's everything. The particular solution, expressed symbolically.

I'd like to check it out. So \$R_1=1\:\text{k}\Omega\$, \$R_2=2\:\text{k}\Omega\$, \$C_1=220\:\text{nF}\$, and \$C_2=470\:\text{nF}\$. From these, I find that:

$$\begin{align*}
V_1&\approx 12-2.521\exp(-6818.182\,t)-9.478992\cdot\exp(-3941.0058 \,t)*\cosh(3270.46431\,t)
\\\\
V_2&\approx 12-\exp(-3941.0058\,t)\cdot(12\cosh(3270.46431\,t)+14.4603534\sinh(3270.46431\,t))
\end{align*}$$

From DESMOS, those two equations plot out as:

[image]

The blue line is \$V_1\$ and the green line is \$V_2\$.

And here's the LTspice plot:

[image]

These look very close so I think I may have my algebra correct. Hope so. Certainly, the approach I followed is correct.

Comment: So where is the Thevenin circuit reduction?:)

Comment: @RussellH  I'm responding directly to the questioner's quandary described in their last paragraph and ignoring inapplicable words. But if you can show how to reduce the circuit per Thevenin's theorem to produce both of the quantitative time-domain voltage answers that accurately match simulation asked for by the questioner, I'd appreciate and benefit from your shared wisdom and offer my thanks. (The green line, especially, would be a treat for me to see Thevenin's theorem applied towards a quantitative result.)

Comment: @periblepsis Hey! thank you for your explanation.  However, as RusselH asked, my problem is NOT in obtaining the equation for the circuit, as you did and as other have tried to help with.  The question I originally asked is precisley HOW to obtain the THEVENIN EQUIVALENT CIRCUIT for the original circuit.  But thanks for your explanation

Comment: @lm555cn No problem. My misunderstanding only. I read your attempts at using Thevenin and I've frankly no clue how you can use them if you are looking to predict the charging times of the original circuit. If you figure out how, let me know. I think you are totally off-base believing in the idea. But that's just me. Smarter people may know better. Some such may exist here and decide to share.